# IEnumerable Type List Conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, viewmodel, asp.net-core-6.0

How to convert user-defined class (view model) to `IEnumerable` list type?

I want to display all the data from the view model class.

```
namespace DBCOntextClass.Models.Classes
{
    public class UserRoleList
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserPassword { get; set; }
        public string? RoleName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
public IActionResult Index(UserRoleList _userRoleList)
{
    var res = _context.TbUsers.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec [dbo].[sp_DisplayRoleNameInUserList] ");
            
    IEnumerable<UserRoleList> _userRoleList = res;

    return View(res);
}
```

```
@model IEnumerable<DBCOntextClass.Models.Classes.UserRoleList>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, may have different names due to you data structure of res but you should be able to see with IntelliSense:

```
 var res = _context.TbUsers.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec [dbo].[sp_DisplayRoleNameInUserList] ").ToList(); 

 var results = res.Select(a => new UserRoleList
            {
                UserId = a.UserId,
                UserName = a.UserName,
                UserPassword = a.UserPassword,
                RoleName = a.RoleName
                
            }).ToList();

 return View(results);
```